# How to get specific number of images with Activity Results API

Tags: java, android

I can get multiple images using GetMultipleContents as shown below, I just want to limit the number of selected images to for example 6.

```
getContent.launch("image/*");

ActivityResultLauncher<String> getContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                //Use URI here
            }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetMultipleContents` uses [`Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE), which is what allows users to select multiple images. However, there is no separate extra that sets any maximum number of images - the user can either select only a single image (when the flag isn't set i.e., you're using `GetContent`) or as many images as they want with no limit.

You can, of course, only actually process the first 6 images of the list you get back.